# Does using readfile to allow users to download images from my server without seeing the image's URL put strain on the server?

Tags: php, ios, mobile, permissions

I'm building an iOS app that allows users to upload photos to an upload folder on my server and send them to their friends. Right now I have the permissions on the uploads folder set to 773 (write, execute are on for World but read is not). This allows users to upload photos from the app successfully into this folder and also allows them to view them later provided they have the direct URL for that particular folder (which they do because the app handles that).

What I'm afraid of is someone getting into the uploads folder and being able to view/download every photo in it.

So one of my first instincts was to create a PHP page that uses readfile to dump the contents of whatever photo the user is asking for (once I've verified that it is indeed the user who took/uploaded the photo or one of their friends trying to view it).

But, I thought, doesn't this put extra strain on the server?

In short, I'm asking if directly downloading a photo using its URL on my server is in any way more efficient than a readfile dump.

Comment: Yes it is more efficient for the server to directly access the file instead of passing it though a PHP file.  Say an image is sent to 1000 friends, the PHP file will need to read that file 1000 times, if its a direct URL Apache will cache that file in memory and the image will be delivered more efficiently.

Comment: Yeah I figured it'd be something like that. All right, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your php script is uploading the images, your folder permissions should only allow access to the user that PHP is being ran as not World.

If the photos are low-risk you could randomize the file names and provide the name to the users permitted to see them. Use an index page in the folder that prevents browsing.

If the photos are higher risk, block web access to the folder and send the file contents as a stream from php. Reading them through a php script requires a small amount of overhead but does not add that much more of an impact on server resources.